# WinUI 3: Is there any way to make generated Window classes from XAML other than MainWindow also extend winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window

Tags: winui-3, windows-app-sdk

Or is there a way to cast them to winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window?

If not, does that mean I have to do the following things with the help of some custom classes applied to manage extra windows?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/system-backdrop-controller

So far, I'm able to invoke a new window through declaring Window object and setting the content from a XAML. But it's sort of inconvenient and limited for my part.

Comment: What doesn't work if you change `runtimeclass MyOtherWindow : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page` to `runtimeclass MyOtherWindow : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window` in `MyOtherWindow.idl`?

Comment: @SimonMourier  Thanks, guy. I haven't expected that BlankWindow generated by VS would have a runtime  class of Page instead of Window. That's quite illogical. 

Comment: It's because with UWP (which most WinUI3 source code is based on), you only had one window. With WinUI3 you can have multiple ones (which is why Window.Current is always null https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.corewindow?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3)